# Issue with Graphlib-dot Parser

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to turn my .dot file from Graphviz output into an SVG so I can manipulate it with D3.js. Right now, I am just trying to read in my .dot file and print it to the console. Currently, this is the javascript I have

```
var fs = require('fs');
var dot = require('graphlib-dot');
var graph = dot.read(fs.readFileSync('profile.dot', 'UTF-8'));
console.log(dot.write(graph));
```

When I try to run my file in node, I get the following error

```
/Users/blank/node_modules/graphlib-dot/lib/dot-grammar.js:114
          result[k] = v[3];
                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of null
    at peg$c34 (/Users/blank/node_modules/graphlib-dot/lib/dot-grammar.js:114:28)
at peg$parseidDef (/Users/blank/node_modules/graphlib-dot/lib/dot-grammar.js:1421:16)
at peg$parseaList (/Users/blank/node_modules/graphlib-dot/lib/dot-grammar.js:1144:12)
at peg$parseattrListBlock (/Users/blank/node_modules/graphlib-dot/lib/dot-grammar.js:1093:16)
at peg$parseattrList (/Users/blank/node_modules/graphlib-dot/lib/dot-grammar.js:1012:12)
at peg$parsenodeStmt (/Users/blank/node_modules/graphlib-dot/lib/dot-grammar.js:808:16)
at peg$parsestmt (/Users/blank/node_modules/graphlib-dot/lib/dot-grammar.js:689:20)
at peg$parsestmtList (/Users/blank/node_modules/graphlib-dot/lib/dot-grammar.js:615:22)
at peg$parsegraphStmt (/Users/blank/node_modules/graphlib-dot/lib/dot-grammar.js:452:28)
at Object.parse (/Users/blank/node_modules/graphlib-dot/lib/dot-grammar.js:2372:18)
```

Here is my .dot file

```
digraph G {
    pad = 0.5;
    nodesep = 0.5;
"legend" [label = < <table border="0" cellborder="1" 
cellspacing="0"><tr><td>Helix</td><td>Triplet</td> 
<td>Frequency</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>1 73 8</td><td>1000</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>50 66 5</td><td>656</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>17 32 5</td><td>614</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>12 36 6</td><td>585</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>40 52 5</td><td>545</td></tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td>13 47 8</td><td>278</td></tr>
</table>>, shape = plaintext, fontsize=11];
"1 2 3 4 5 " [shape = box];
"1 2 6 " [shape = box];
"1 3 4 5 " [shape = box];
"1 " [shape = box];
"1 2 " [style = dashed];
"1 2 3 4 5 " [label = "[1[4[3]][5][2]]\n372/372"];
"1 2 6 " [label = "[1[6][2]]\n208/238"];
"1 3 4 5 " [label = "[1[4[3]][5]]\n165/537"];
"1 " [label = "[1]\n121/1000"];
"1 2 " [label = "[1[2]]\n12/656"];
"1 " [label = "[1]\n121/1000"];
"1 3 4 5 " -> "1 2 3 4 5 " [label = "2 ", arrowhead = vee];
"1 2 " -> "1 2 3 4 5 " [label = "3 4 5 ", arrowhead = vee];
"1 2 " -> "1 2 6 " [label = "6 ", arrowhead = vee];
"1 " -> "1 2 3 4 5 " [label = "2 3 4 5 ", arrowhead = vee];
"1 " -> "1 2 6 " [label = "2 6 ", arrowhead = vee];
"1 " -> "1 3 4 5 " [label = "3 4 5 ", arrowhead = vee];
"1 " -> "1 " [label = "", arrowhead = vee];
"1 " -> "1 2 " [label = "2 ", arrowhead = vee];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand if the issue is with your DOT or the graphlib-dot code, you could try using a different library such as https://github.com/anvaka/dotparser/ or https://github.com/siefkenj/dotgraph. If one of the other libraries work, then its likely an issue with graphlib-dot. Hope that helps!